# Python - Continuously Looping a Function

Tags: python, function, loops

Python newbie here so excuse the bad coding do.Ob

When I run the following.....

```
def bug_check():
        for host in hosts:
            sshInteract.send('ssh ' + host )
            try: 
                sshInteract.expect(ep1)
                sshInteract.send(password)
                sshInteract.expect(ep2)
            except: 
                print("SSH unsuccessful")
            else:
                sshInteract.send("exit")
                sshInteract.expect(ep3)
                print("SSH successful")

bug_check()
```

...the print output I get (which is correct) based on the three hosts in my list is:

```
SSH successful
SSH successful
SSH unsuccessful
```

What I would like to do is to continuously run this every 60 seconds until I manually stop it. So what I did was the following:

```
def bug_check():
        for host in hosts:
            sshInteract.send('ssh ' + host )
            try: 
                sshInteract.expect(ep1)
                sshInteract.send(password)
                sshInteract.expect(ep2)
            except: 
                print("SSH unsuccessful")
            else:
                sshInteract.send("exit")
                sshInteract.expect(ep3)
                print("SSH successful")

while True:
    bug_check()
    time.sleep(60)
```

When running this, the print output looks like this which is incorrect:

```
SSH successful
SSH successful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH unsuccessful
```

What it should look like is:

```
SSH successful
SSH successful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH successful
SSH successful
SSH unsuccessful
SSH successful
SSH successful
SSH unsuccessful
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your expect is in some bad state?

Comment: Without knowing what `sshInteract` is exactly, it's impossible to say. Possible when it first fails, it enters a state where you need to reinitialise, or perhaps there's some extra needed to reconnect to the same host there. Please provide the imports and tell use what library you're using.

Comment: Printing the stacktrace in `except` might help.